# Specifiying a route with mutiple stops

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm trying to plot a route on a google map using `ggmap` that has multiple stops.  I'm using the code below.

```
library("ggmap")

legs_df <- route('The Blackhouse Grill, 19 Newgate Street, Chester CH1 1DE, United Kingdom',
  c('CH2 3GH, Chester, UK',
  'CH3 3ET, Chester, UK','CH2 1ET, Chester, UK'),mode = c("walking")
)

qmap('Chester, UK', zoom = 15, maptype = 'hybrid',
     base_layer = ggplot(aes(x = startLon, y = startLat), data = legs_df)) +
  geom_leg(aes(x = startLon, y = startLat, xend = endLon, yend = endLat,
        colour = route),
    alpha = 2/4, size = 2, data = legs_df)
```

The problem is I receive an error, Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous

> Error in data.frame(x = c(-2.8886032, -2.8884907, -2.8822871, -2.875769,  :
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the way you are specifying the colour. If you don't want to colour each leg in a different colour, then you should specify the colour outside of the `aes` function like this:

```
qmap('Chester, UK', zoom = 15, maptype = 'hybrid',
     base_layer = ggplot(aes(x = startLon, y = startLat), data = legs_df)) +
  geom_leg(aes(x = startLon, y = startLat, xend = endLon, yend = endLat),
           alpha = 2/4, size = 2, data = legs_df, colour = 'red')
```

Which results in:

[image]

The error you were getting is because you specified `route` as your colour, and `route` is a function. So it didn't know how to map the function as a colour.